# texture transparency

Tags: c#, xna, textures, xna-4.0

I got some problem with texture transparency, I hope ya can help.

Details:

- XNA 4.0
- Texture source is BMP, what I make transparent by code:

  ```
  public void Feketealapú(string Azonosító)
  {
    //textúra megállapítása
    Texture2D Textúra = Textúrák[TextúraSzáma(Azonosító)];

    //adatok lekérése
    Color[] buffer = new Color[Textúra.Width * Textúra.Height];
    Textúra.GetData<Color>(buffer);

    //adatok módosítása
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
      Color szín = buffer[i];
      szín.A = ((byte)((szín.R + szín.B + szín.G) / 3));
      buffer[i] = szín;
    }

    //adatok visszaírása
    Textúra.SetData<Color>(buffer);
  }
  ```
- I use the following before I start drawing 3d stuff:

  ```
  public void Rajzolj()
  {
    GStatic.Játék.GrafikaiCsatorna.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
    GStatic.Játék.GrafikaiCsatorna.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
    GStatic.Játék.GrafikaiCsatorna.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
    GStatic.Játék.GrafikaiCsatorna.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
  ```

  ..etc.
- If I use BlendState.Opaque I get no transparent textures.
- I get into the following trouble: http://youtu.be/ZiPzyk7AWu8
- **Edit:** Bit more detail about the problem is: the problem is with the transparent texture, what simulates a fire effect. The fire is from several rectangles with these transparent textures. If I see the fire from an angle, I should see another fire effect's rectangle through the transparent texture, what is also transparent. The problem is that **instead of this, I see the floor's texture behind the model instead**.

So could someone help me out a bit?

Thanks in advance: 
Péter

Comment: Have you considered a constrained billboard instead of 4 quads. It would solve this problem with fewer vertices & code.

Comment: +1 Very nice idea indeed, but I do not want it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I don't think the transparency is the issue. I think that whats happening is the first thing in the Z-Buffer is being draw and nothing else behind it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/02/18/depth-sorting-alpha-blended-objects.aspx

The most import part being the where he specifies how best to order your scene and manipulate the DepthBuffer.

1. Set DepthBufferEnable and DepthBufferWriteEnable to true
2. Draw all opaque geometry
3. Leave DepthBufferEnable set to true, but change DepthBufferWriteEnable to false
4. Sort alpha blended objects by distance from the camera, then draw them in order from back to front

Comment: Did not work for me, but thank you. (Also has a division by zero if color is black.) I even tried to make it new Color(szín.R, szín.G, szín.B, 0.5f) to have half transparent, but the problem still there: you see floor instead of another fire effect (texture) through the transparency.

Comment: I rewatched the video and don't think the transparency is the issue. Rewrote the post to reflect my altered opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot. I was able to fix up the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is neither a transparency issue or an ordering issue that you can solve.

The nature of your layout has all 4 quads overlapping each other so that each quad needs to be both in front of and behind another quad at the same time.

So setting draw order won't help because half of quad A needs to be drawn before quad B and the other half of quad A needs to be drawn after quad B.

It may get a little bit better if you divide it into 8 quads that all meet in the middle and sort/draw by depth from the camera. But if you go this route, 3 quads may be sufficient.

Comment: I was pretty lucky, because idea above worked like a charm, so I did not needed to alter the model. What I did was just collecting those draw data I would make with transparency, drawing the rest with opaque, then after all of these done, I draw the transparent stuff with alpha; with dephtbufferenable and writeenable stuff.

Edit: did not need to sort things so far, may be only luck, but did not needed to.